# loadable library and perl binaries mismatch on a custom xs after upgrading to 5.26

Tags: c++, perl, perl-module, perl-xs

I have an application which has C++ and perl modules.
I have a custom xs module crypt.xs (not a module provided with perl)
Previously our perl module was built with 5.16.0 perl version.

I have another C# application which executes some perl command through System.Diagnostics.Process.

All these were working fine until i upgraded the perl version to 5.26.2

After upgrading, the same System.Diagnostics.Process throes a standard error

```
"crypt.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0000000011800080, needed 0000000011C00080)"
```

I googled and found many threads for the same issue but everywhere the problem is with a standard perl module and rebuilding using cpan or pacman solves the issue.

But here its a custom user defined xs module.

Moreover i use cmake to find perl libs and i have updated the version it. So dont know why this error occurs still.

How would i go about it to debug?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: When upgrading the Perl major version, you need to recompile all XS modules

Comment: compilation happens in windows machine and it is supposed to have happened in perl 5.26.2.  I am not able to verify if the xs modules are recompiled properly though. Any clue on that ?

Comment: XS modules are not automatically recompiled. You will need to reinstall the XS module ideally from source.

Comment: I have a cmakelist file for the xs modules and I can see with the build logs that the crypt.xs is compiled to crypt.xs.cpp and then to crypt.c which is bundled to a dll. And as the FindPerl.cmake finds 5.26.2 Perl version the xs must have recompiled , is my understanding right ? I have pm files too. Should they also be recompiled ?

Comment: how do we determine which perl version the xs module is compiled with?

Comment: Using `cmake` to compile Perl XS modules is quite nonstandard. I recommend compiling and installing the modules using `cpan That::Module` (if it's on CPAN) or `cpan .` from the respective module distribution directory (if the module is private). If you have more than one Perl executable, clean up the environment so that only the Perl executable and scripts from one version are visible.

Comment: Re "*the problem is with a standard perl module and rebuilding using cpan or pacman solves the issue.*" The problem, as always, is with an XS module that was installed by a different version of Perl than the one using it. In fact, it's very unlikely to happen to a standard module (unless you've done something very weird); it will happen when you install a module a module to a non-standard location (e.g. using local::lib) and tell two Perls to use that location.